# django-admin start project returns command not found on mac with django version 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, django

I just started learning django and to start my first project,
I have installed Python version 3.10.0 on mac. created a virtual environment and installed django but when trying to run django-admin startproject myproject  in virtual environment, it returns command not found.

could this be a bug on the latest version of python or there is something else I should try ?

Comment: try to install django again inside the virtual environment

Comment: and put a screenshot from your terminal in your question.

Comment: What is the output of the following commands in your virtual environment: `python --version` and `python -m pip show django` ?